How is the DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject project property in WinUI projects in a MAUI muli-project calculated?
The project file of the WinUI project in our new MAUI multi-project app contains the code below as default:
<!--
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
-->
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
</ItemGroup>

<!--
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project 

even if
        the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
-->
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
</PropertyGroup>

I am experiencing an intermittent issue where my "Package and Publish" menu vanishes and MSIX files are not created on builds.  I suspect that the project property DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject is evaluating as false for some currently unknown reason.
I cannot find any information about the purpose of the property or how it is calculated or why it might be being set to false.  The only google hits I get are where folks with other issues have posted the contents of their project files.
If I remove it's use as a condition, I get my Package and Publish menu back and MSIX files are created on builds.  But I'm assuming it's been put in for a reason.  I would like to know the reason and how it is calculated.

How can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can test on our side?
